# Form size issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2012

I don't really know how to explain this but I think these two photos are self-explanatory.

Visual Studio

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDkmq.png

Application loaded

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjCVm.png

Why does it resize like this when I haven't set minimum/maximum size properties?

Comment: Set the size of your form in load event and add anchors to your controls

Answer (score 0):

Set Dock of the Listview on Properties window to "Top"

Answer (score 0):

set the `Anchor` property of that control to all, like this:

```
Control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left| AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Anchor property on controls is set to `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left`. This means that the controls will be anchored to the top-left of the form, but will not resize automatically when the form size changes. To achieve this functionality, you have two options:

1. You can set the `Dock` property of the control. This will cause the control to "dock" to a side of the window, or optionally to the entire client area. Docking can greatly simplify control layout, but can be confusing at first, and is not always the optimal method to achieve a desired layout. One example of this behavior is the tree-view on the left side of the Windows Explorer window. More information on docking can be found below:

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4(v=vs.80).aspx
2. You can set the `Anchor` property on controls. This allows for more fine-tuned behavior than docking, in most instances. By setting the `Anchor` property of a control to `AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right`, the control will automatically maintain it's position from the top, left, and right sides of the window as it is resized. If the form width changes, the width of the control will change to remain the same distance from the right edge of the form. To have the height automatically resize as well, you can also set the `AnchorStyles.Bottom` flag. More information on anchoring can be found below:

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx
   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.90).aspx